# getResources in PagerAdapter

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a string array from resources in xml in a class that extends PagerAdapter. I've tried various constructors with no luck. i.e. NullPointerExceptions Any help?
Here's my Adapter:

```
class CharacterViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

CharacterView activity;

public Object mPagerAdapter(Context context) {

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    CONTENT = res.getStringArray(R.array.heroes);

    return CONTENT;
}

public int getCount() {
    return CONTENT.length;
}

public CharacterViewPagerAdapter(CharacterView activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

public Object instantiateItem(final View collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    int resId = R.layout.character_profile;
    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
    activity.initPagerView(position, view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return CharacterViewPagerAdapter.CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
}
}
```

The CONTENT variable is still null. I need help initialising it

Comment: Share some code. The Developers to understand and solve your problem.

Comment: Hello Innen Tensai, where is your CONTENT declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it this way:

```
class CharacterViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

CharacterView activity;
static Context context;

static Resources res = null;
static String[] CONTENT = null;

public int getCount() {
    return CONTENT.length;
}

public CharacterViewPagerAdapter(CharacterView activity, Context c) {
    this.activity = activity;
    context = c;
    res = context.getResources();
    ArrayList<String> CONTENT = new ArrayList<String>();
    CONTENT = res.getStringArray(R.array.CONTENT);
    Collections.addAll(CONTENT, CONTENT);
    Collections.sort(CONTENT);
    CONTENT = new String[CONTENT.size()];
    CONTENT = CONTENT.toArray(CONTENT);
}

public Object instantiateItem(final View collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    int resId = R.layout.character_profile;
    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
    activity.initPagerView(position, view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return CharacterViewPagerAdapter.CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
}
}
```

works like a dream :-) Thanks!